# Editing attributes in LuaXML

Tags: xml, lua, luaxml

I've been able to save and load XML files, but I'm having issues actually affecting a number in them. Here's my example:

```
require 'luaxml'

local text = [[
<Viewers>
  <eaglesfan0251>
    <Minutes>0</Minutes>
    <Minutes>eaglesfan0251</Minutes>
  </eaglesfan0251>
  <managarmr83>
    <Minutes>1</Minutes>
    <Minutes>managarmr83</Minutes>
  </managarmr83>
  <gorbatron5000>
    <Minutes>2</Minutes>
  </gorbatron5000>
</Viewers>
]]


local t = xml.eval(text)

for a, b in pairs(t:find("gorbatron5000","Minutes")) do
    if b.TAG ~= nil then
        if b[b.TAG] == "Minutes" then
            print(b[a])
            t:append("Minutes")[a] = "0"
        end
    end
end

print(t)
```

This adds a second Minutes tag after the spot I'm trying to affect. Basically I want to be able to read the minutes, then change it and update the XML.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong on this, but isn't the second attribute in find the attribute of the tag you're looking for?

I think your code should be this, based on the documentation:

```
local t = xml.eval(text)

local node = t:find("gorbatron5000")
if node ~= nil then
  print(node[1]) -- Minutes if your first child
  node[1] = 0
end
```

source: http://viremo.eludi.net/LuaXML/
more detailed:

> **function xml.find(var, tag, attributeKey,attributeValue)** 
>   recursively parses a Lua table for a substatement fitting to the provided tag > and attribute
>
> ```
> param var, the table to be searched in.
> param tag (optional) the xml tag to be found.
> param attributeKey (optional) the exact attribute to be found.
> param attributeValue (optional) the attribute value to be found.
> Returns the first (sub-)table which matches the search condition or nil.
> ```

So my understand leads to the code I wrote.
Let me know if this helps, as I'm learning Lua myself as well.

Comment: I've tried that already, which returns <Minutes>2</Minutes> rather than just 2. I could parse the text to narrow it down, but I was hoping for a more direct solution. I also don't really understand how to write to that part, I can append another <Minutes>2</Minutes>, but I don't understand how to change that existing one to be <Minutes>3</Minutes>.